# Pulling data from multiple tables in MySQL without duplicates

Tags: mysql

I am new to SQL so this might be a very basic question.

I have two tables -

```
W

W.Company, W.Kind, W.Region

P

P.Company, P.Kind, P.Region
```

I want to pull Company, Kind, and Region data from the two tables, matching on companies. Kind entries are the same, Regions differ between the two tables.

When I write the query below, I get results with duplicate values.

```
SELECT W.Company, W.Kind, W.Region, P.Region
FROM W
LEFT JOIN P ON W.Company = P.Company
WHERE P.Facility IS NOT NULL;
```

I just need the 6 regions but they repeat themselves in order to match the number of rows. Is it possible to combine the regions into 1 column but still show which table they come from?

[Example of pulled data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ybEmb.png)

Thank you

Comment: Can you give us the expected result?

Comment: Is this is you looking for ? `select company, kind, region from w where facility is not null union select company, kind, region from p where facility is not`

Comment: Thanks DanB, your query pulls everything into one column, in order to differentiate the region source, I included an additional column to show the source table.     SELECT Company, Kind, Region, 'from W' AS source
  FROM W
UNION ALL
SELECT Company, Kind, Region, 'from P'
  FROM P
ORDER
    BY Company, Kind, Region